# Erro na instalação do Chatterbot (python)

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot

Toda vez que tento instalar o Chatterbot seja através do pip ou pip3 ele dá um erro gigante. Vi em algumas perguntas que ao instalar o python 64bits ele resolveria, fiz isso mas nada. Inclusive, o python 3.8 64-bits já está no PATH. Como posso resolver? Segue o erro:

```
Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\pytho
n\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build
-env-vqj54lxb\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setupt
ools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7
.1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (193 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/a2/82b506a6cdb42cc79a65d5a9e790112cf6b98ee7aba4a53a2b9c9c8047d0/s
etuptools-42.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/47/1dfa4795e24fd6f93d5d58602dd716c3f101cfd5a77cd9acbe519b44a0a9/w
heel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/2c/9d873fc8d1be29af12a1d41707461399327396da10e50e183754aa4136b9/C
ython-0.29.14-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/1f/43be34e4decc602fae2bda73b05525bc49deff44baeb95611b23a2929195/c
ymem-2.0.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0b/14/c9aa735cb9c131545fc9e23031baccb87041ac9215b3d75f99e3cf18f6a3/p
reshed-2.0.1.tar.gz
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5b/73/129c1aed56c88a446c70e4eda186fe014bfb8330478e5e257cc923bd3e15/m
urmurhash-1.0.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/39/ea2a3d5b87fd52fc865fd1ceb7b91dca1f85e227d53e7a086d260f6bcb93/t
hinc-7.0.8.tar.gz
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys
.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AMANDA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e1cn6kbl\\thinc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\
\AMANDA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e1cn6kbl\\thinc\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__)
;code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-
base 'C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e1cn6kbl\thinc\pip-egg-info'
           cwd: C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e1cn6kbl\thinc\
      Complete output (173 lines):
      Could not locate executable g77
      Could not locate executable f77
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
      Could not locate executable f90
      Could not locate executable DF
      Could not locate executable efl
      Could not locate executable gfortran
      Could not locate executable f95
      Could not locate executable g95
      Could not locate executable efort
      Could not locate executable efc
      Could not locate executable flang
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      'svnversion' nÆo ' reconhecido como um comando interno
      ou externo, um programa oper vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
      non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
      Running from numpy source directory.
      C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\setup.py:419: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptool
s command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
        run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
      C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
          Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
          Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
          A better performance should be easily gained by switching
          Blas library.
        self.calc_info()
      C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
          the BLAS environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
          the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:

          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
      C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:

          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
      c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution opt
ion: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in s
ave_modules
          yield saved
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in s
etup_context
          yield
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in r
un_setup
          _execfile(setup_script, ns)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _e
xecfile
          exec(code, globals, locals)
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\setup.py", line 444, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\setup.py", line 436, in setup_package
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in se
tup
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in
setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line
 163, in run
          self.run_command("egg_info")
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", lin
e 26, in run
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", li
ne 142, in run
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", li
ne 153, in build_sources
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", li
ne 286, in build_library_sources
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", li
ne 369, in generate_sources
        File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 669, in get_mathlib_info
      RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e1cn6kbl\thinc\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e1cn6kbl\thinc\setup.py", line 201, in setup_package
          setup(
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in
setup
          _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in
_install_setup_requires
          dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetc
h_build_eggs
          resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780,
in resolve
          dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065,
 in best_match
          return self.obtain(req, installer)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077,
 in obtain
          return installer(requirement)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetc
h_build_egg
          return cmd.easy_install(req)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", l
ine 679, in easy_install
          return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", l
ine 705, in install_item
          dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", l
ine 890, in install_eggs
          return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", l
ine 1158, in build_and_install
          self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", l
ine 1144, in run_setup
          run_setup(setup_script, args)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in r
un_setup
          raise
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
          self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in s
etup_context
          yield
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
          self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in s
ave_modules
          saved_exc.resume()
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in r
esume
          six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685,
in reraise
          raise value.with_traceback(tb)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in s
ave_modules
          yield saved
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in s
etup_context
          yield
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in r
un_setup
          _execfile(setup_script, ns)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _e
xecfile
          exec(code, globals, locals)
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\setup.py", line 444, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\setup.py", line 436, in setup_package
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in se
tup
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in
setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line
 163, in run
          self.run_command("egg_info")
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", lin
e 26, in run
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", li
ne 142, in run
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", li
ne 153, in build_sources
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", li
ne 286, in build_library_sources
        File "C:\Users\AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-_175y485\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", li
ne 369, in generate_sources
        File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 669, in get_mathlib_info
      RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
      LINK : fatal error LNK1104: não é possível abrir o arquivo 'kernel32.lib'
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\
amanda\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\
AMANDA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vqj54lxb\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -
i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurha
sh>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score -1):

Opa, Já conseguiu resolver o problema?

Se ainda não conseguiu, tente usar o python 3.7.7, desinstale o 3.8.4,
e na própria instalação do 3.7.7 clique em Add to Path, depois no cmd digite:

```
pip install chatterbot
```

O link para o python 3.7.7 está aqui (64 bits).

```
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.7/python-3.7.7-amd64.exe
```

(32 bits)

```
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.7/python-3.7.7.exe
```

Qualquer coisa avisa aqui que eu tive o mesmo problema!